# Cannot create htpasswd

Tags: ubuntu

I have a fresh ubuntu setup, with the latest version of `apache2-utils` installed.

I'm trying to create a new `.httpasswd` file at `/etc/nginx/.htpasswd` (new file), using `bcrypt` encryption with a Cost of 10.

This is the command I've tried, however the output is the help for `htpasswd` and no file is created. Is there something obvious I'm perhaps missing?

```
 htpasswd -bcB -C 10 /etc/nginx/.htpasswd mypasswordHere
```

P.S. tried it with and without `sudo`.

Comment: You are missing a username to your password. Is that an error from copying?

Comment: @roaima, I am checking for the file and it's not there :)

Comment: @FelixJN, that was it! I've been completely blind, focusing mostly on the flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `-b` flag will need providing a username and password:

```
htpasswd -bcB -C 10 path/to/htpawssd username password
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the username from the command line

Answer (score 0):

for me,

- I first navigated to the dir where i want to save the password file
- then ran `htpasswd -c .htpasswd as1` to create the file for the user - `as1`